# Nesting shared subresource in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am wondering how to differentiate between requests from different parent resources in a subresource.

Consider the subresource comments, which is shared both by posts and users. How does the comments controller know what the correct parent resource is?

I got these routes:

```php
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentsController');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('users.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

In `CommentsController`, I got this function:

```php
public function index($parent_id) {
    // return multiple comments here
}
```

So I may want to display all the comments belonging to a post or all the comments belonging to a user, but how can the `CommentsController` tell if `$parent_id` refers to a post or a user in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have `Route::model` bindings, so that instead of id's, models are passed to your controller actions, consider the following to distinguish between Users and Posts:

```
Route::model('post', 'Post');
Route::model('user', 'User');
Route::model('comment', 'Comment');

Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentsController');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('users.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

Then, if you want to ensure the argument type in your action definition, simply make Users and Posts extend from some abstract base class like this:

```
abstract class Commentable extends \Eloquent {}

class User extends Commentable {}
```

Now you can use the following in your controller:

```
class CommentsController extends BaseController {
    function index(Commentable $commentable, Comment $comment) {
        // Possibly check if this comment and the given commentable are even related...
        dd($commentable); // make your logic check if it is an instanceof User or Post!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentsController');
Route::resource('users.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

To get parent use this

```
$parent = Request::segment(1) === 'posts' ? 'posts' : 'users';
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about `Request::segment()`. :P

You should use `posts.comments` and `users.comments` instead of with a `/`, for nested resources though. Great tutorial here: https://tutsplus.com/lesson/nested-resources/